# How to listen the state changes in svelte like useEffect

Tags: state, use-effect, svelte

I have read some article about state change listener, As I am a very beginner to the svelte environment I can't figure out what is the most efficient way to listen to the state change.

Let us take  state variable  as `X` and `Y`

#### Method 1:

```js
$: if (X||Y) {
    console.log("yes");
}
```

#### Method 2:

Use a combination of `afterUpdate` and `onDestroy`

REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/300c16ee38af49e98261eef02a9b04a8?version=3.38.2

```js
import { afterUpdate, onDestroy } from 'svelte';

export function useEffect(cb, deps) {
    let cleanup;
    
    function apply() {
        if (cleanup) cleanup();
        cleanup = cb();
    }
    
    if (deps) {
        let values = [];
        afterUpdate(() => {
            const new_values = deps();
            if (new_values.some((value, i) => value !== values[i])) {
                apply();
                values = new_values;
            }
        });
    } else {
        // no deps = always run
        afterUpdate(apply);
    }
    
    onDestroy(() => {
        if (cleanup) cleanup();
    });
}
```

#### Method 3:

Use `writable` and `subscribe`

```html
<script>
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
const X = writable(0);
const Y = writable(0);


X.subscribe(value => {
    console.log("X was changed", value);
});


Y.subscribe(value => {
      console.log("Y was changed", value);
});

</script>

<button on:click={(e)=>{
    X.update((val)=>val++)
}}>Change X</button>
<button on:click={(e)=>{
    Y.update((val)=>val++)
}}>Change Y</button>
```

Comment: What is most efficient depends on your use case. There isn't a one-size-fits-all solution to this.

Comment: The common way is method 1, why make it more complicated ?

Comment: When I try to use Method 1, it doesn't fire always. https://svelte.dev/repl/3cb4c229c334488883db49383656ec26?version=3.38.2

Comment: The code you link has an error as it uses the undefined variable `name`

Comment: yes and it always fires doesn't it ?

Comment: Yes, it works fine. But JSHeap memory keeps getting increasing. https://imgur.com/BrsbTjN

Comment: I don't see anything suspicious in that graph. Garbage collection runs from time to time, not immediately when the space is no longer needed. Also keep in mind that you are running this code inside the REPL, this cannot be compared to running the code in your own app.

Comment: Yeah understood

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Reactive statements

Svelte does not have an equivalent of useEffect. Instead, Svelte has reactive statements.

```
// Svelte
// doubled will always be twice of single. If single updates, doubled will run again.
$: doubled = single * 2

// equivalent to this React

let single = 0
const [doubled, setDoubled] = useState(single * 2)

useEffect(() => {
  setDoubled(single * 2)
}, [single])
```

This may seem like magic, since you don't define dependencies or teardown functions, but Svelte takes care of all that under the hood. Svelte is smart enough to figure out the dependencies and only run each reactive statement as needed.

So if you want to run a callback every time a value updates, you can simply do this.

```
<script>
  let value = ''
  $: console.log(value)
</script>

<input type='text' name='name' bind:value />
```

In short, this will console log the value of the input every time the input's value changes.

### Recreating your suggestions

#### Method 1

That's about as concise as you can go, and is my go-to means of listening to state changes unless I need something more complex.

```
$: if(x || y) console.log('yes')
```

Though note that there may be a subtle bug here. If `x` or `y` were both truthy then turn falsy (e.g., they both became empty strings), this statement will not run.

#### Method 2

Here, you basically recreated React's `useEffect`. This works, but you can simplify the implementation in your REPL a lot using reactive statements.

```
<script>
    let count = 1;
    $: console.log(count)
</script>

<input type="number" bind:value={count}>
```

#### Method 3

Stores are great for passing data between components without using props or context. Check out this answer for more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67681054/11506995

In this case, though, we can simplify everything using regular reactive context (again).

```
<script>
  let x = 0
  let y = 0

  $: console.log('x was changed', x)
  $: console.log('y was changed', y)
</script>

<button on:click={() => x++}>Change x</button>
<button on:click={() => y++}>Change x</button>
```

---

I also have a detailed answer of comparing React's `context`/`useEffect` with Svelte's `context`/`stores`/reactive statements in [Understanding Context in Svelte (convert from React Context)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67663671/understanding-context-in-svelte-convert-from-react-context)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67681054/11506995

Comment: The first method could be `$: x, y, console.log('yes')`. It might be less readable but it eliminates the subtle bug you mentioned. https://svelte.dev/repl/319aac5e49714b72b5119fd6480d9c64

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

```
<script>
    let count = 0;
    
    $: doubled = (() => {
        return count * 2
    })()

    function handleClick() {
        count += 1;
    }
</script>

<button on:click={handleClick}>
    Clicked {count} {count === 1 ? 'time' : 'times'}
</button>

<p>{count} doubled is {doubled}</p>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).